# A curious Hankel determinant

Tags: combinatorics, determinant

Define the sequence  $a_{n}$ by $a_{n}=1$ if $n+1=2^k$ for some $k$ and $a_{n}=0$ else.

Computer experiments suggest that the determinant of the Hankel matrix 
$$H_{n+1}:=\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{0} & a_{1} & \dots & a_{n}\\
 a_{1} & a_{2} & \dots & a_{n+1}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 a_{n} & a_{n+1} & \dots & a_{2n}
      \end{pmatrix}$$
satisfies $$\det{H_{n+1}}=(-1)^\binom{n+1}{2}.$$
Is there a simple way to prove this?

**Edit:**
Let $H_{n}=(h(i,j)).$ 
For each $n$  there is a unique permutation of ${(0,1,\dots,n-1)}$ such that the determinant of $H_{n}$ equals $h_{0,p(0)}h_{1,p(1)}\dots h_{n-1,p(n-1)}.$

Let me show this in the following example where for clarity I have set $a(n)=x(n)$ if $n+1$ is a power of $2.$
$$H_{9}=\begin{pmatrix}
 x(0) & x(1) & 0 & x(3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(7)& 0\\
 x(1) & 0 & x(3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(7) & 0& 0\\
    0 & x(3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(7) & 0 & 0& 0\\
    x(3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(7) & 0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
 0&0&0&x(7)&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&x(7)&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&x(7)&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    x(7) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&x(15)\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x(15)& 0
      \end{pmatrix}$$
If we  go from right to left we see that $p(8)=7,p(7)=8.$ Then $p(6)=1,p(5)=2,p(4)=3,p(3)=4,p(2)=5,p(1)=6.$ There remains $p(0)=0.$ In general the same procedure works.
Thus my question reduces to a proof of the fact that the sign of this permutation is $(-1)^\binom{n}{2}.$

Comment: So let's say that a permutation $\tau$ of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ (for $n \in \mathbb{N}$) is *nimble* if for each $i \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$, the number $i + \tau\left(i\right)$ is a power of $2$. You claim that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a unique nimble permutation $\sigma_n$ of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$, and that its sign is $\left(-1\right)^{n\left(n-1\right)/2}$. I believe that this can be proven by strong induction over $n$. In the induction step, let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $2^k < n \leq 2^{k+1}$, and try to argue that any ...

Comment: ... nimble permutation $\sigma$ of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ must send each $i > 2^{k+1}-n$ to $2^{k+1}-i$. Once this is shown, it will follow immediately that $\sigma$ restricts to an order-reversing permutation of the interval $\left[2^{k+1}-n+1, n\right]$, whereas its restriction to $\left[0, 2^{k+1}-n\right]$ is a nimble permutation of a smaller $n$; this should give a straightforward induction.

Comment: Okay, there are imprecisions in my comments. Read "a power of $2$ minus $1$" instead of "a power of $2$". Some of the strict inequality signs might be weak. But I think the idea is the right one.

Comment: Observation 1: If $i \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ satisfies $i > 2^{k+1}-n$, then both $i$ and $2^{k+1}-i-1$ are elements of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$, and at least one of them is $\geq 2^k$. (To prove this, just assume the contrary and get the obvious contradiction.)

Comment: Observation 2: If $\sigma$ is a nimble permutation, then so is $\sigma^{-1}$. (Obvious.)

Comment: Observation 3: If $2^k < n \leq 2^{k+1}$, and if $\sigma$ is a nimble permutation of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$, and if $i \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ satisfies $i > 2^{k+1}-n$, then $\sigma\left(i\right) = 2^{k+1}-i-1$. (Proof: Observation 1 shows that both $i$ and $2^{k+1}-i$ are elements of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$, and at least one of them is $\geq 2^k$. WLOG assume that $i$ is $\geq 2^k$, because otherwise we can use the nimbleness of $\sigma^{-1}$ to show by the same argument ...

Comment: ... that $\sigma^{-1}\left(2^{k+1}-i-1\right) = 2^{k+1} - \left(2^{k+1}-i-1\right) - 1 = i$, which of course is the same as proving that $\sigma\left(i\right) = 2^{k+1}-i-1$. Now that we have assumed that $i$ is $\geq 2^k$, we recall that $i + \sigma\left(i\right)$ is a power of $2$ minus $1$. Which power of $2$ ? It cannot be $2^k$ or less, since $i \geq 2^k$. But it cannot be $2^{k+2}$ or higher either, since both $i$ and $\sigma\left(i\right)$ are $< n \leq 2^{k+1}$. Thus, ...

Comment: ... the only remaining possibility is $2^{k+1}$. Hence, $i + \sigma\left(i\right) = 2^{k+1} - 1$, so that $\sigma\left(i\right) = 2^{k+1}-i-1$. Qed.)

Comment: Observation 4: If $2^k < n \leq 2^{k+1}$, and if $\sigma$ is a nimble permutation of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$, then $\sigma$ is the disjoint union of a nimble permutation of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,2^{k+1}-n-1\right\}$ with the (unique) order-reversing permutation of the interval $\left\{2^{k+1}-n, 2^{k+1}-n+1, \ldots, n\right\}$. (This follows immediately from Observation 3.)

Comment: Observation 4 proves (by strong induction) that there is exactly one nimble permutation of $\left\{0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ for each given $n$; furthermore, it lets you construct the cycle decomposition of this permutation by recursion. (This works because $2^{k+1}-n<n$ under the assumption that $2^k < n \leq 2^{k+1}$.) Now, getting the sign should be easy.

Comment: Damn, I still have incorrect strict/weak inequality signs floating around and not ime to fix them, but this should be the right way.

Comment: @darij: Thank you very much. This is the proof I have looked for. Why do you not state it as an answer in order that I can accept it ?

Comment: I have posted an answer now; my above comments are obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is -- but this is not really about determinants. Let me introduce
some notations and state the main result.

> **Definition.** Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set $\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots
> \right\}  $. For each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$, we let $\left[
> i,j\right]  $ be the interval $\left\{  i,i+1,\ldots,j\right\}  $ of
>   $\mathbb{N}$ (this is empty when $i>j$).
>
> For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we let $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ be the
>   interval $\left[  0,n-1\right]  =\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $ of
>   $\mathbb{N}$.
>
> **Definition.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $\sigma$ be a permutation
>   of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Then, $\sigma$ is said to be *nimble* if for
>   each $i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $, the number $i+\sigma\left(
> i\right)  +1$ is a power of $2$.

Yes, $1$ counts as a power of $2$. The name "nimble" hints at the game of Nim
(and Nim addition), but I don't have the time to figure out the exact connection.

Here is my main claim (which you conjectured):

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> **(a)** Then, there is a unique nimble permutation $\sigma_{n}$ of
>   $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$.
>
> **(b)** This permutation $\sigma_{n}$ has sign $\left(  -1\right)
> ^{\sigma_{n}}=\left(  -1\right)  ^{n\left(  n-1\right)  /2}$.

This permutation yields your conjecture that $\det\left(  H_{n}\right)
=\left(  -1\right)  ^{n\left(  n-1\right)  /2}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Indeed, if we fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then the determinant of the matrix
$H_{n}=\left(  a_{i+j}\right)  _{i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime};\ j\in\left[
n\right]  ^{\prime}}$ rewrites as
\begin{align*}
\det\left(  H_{n}\right)   &  =\sum_{\sigma\text{ is a permutation of }\left[
n\right]  ^{\prime}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma}\underbrace{a_{0+\sigma\left(
0\right)  }a_{1+\sigma\left(  1\right)  }\cdots a_{n-1+\sigma\left(
n-1\right)  }}_{\substack{=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }\sigma\text{ is nimble};\\
0, & \text{if }\sigma\text{ is not nimble}
\end{cases}
\\\text{(by the definition of the }a_{k}\text{)}}}\\
&  =\sum_{\sigma\text{ is a permutation of }\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}
}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma}
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }\sigma\text{ is nimble};\\
0, & \text{if }\sigma\text{ is not nimble}
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\sum_{\sigma\text{ is a nimble permutation of }\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}
}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma} \\
&  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{n\left(  n-1\right)  /2}\qquad\left(  \text{by
Theorem 1}\right)  .
\end{align*}
So it remains to prove Theorem 1.

We begin with simple lemmas:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $k$ be a positive integer
>   such that $2^{k-1}<n\leq2^{k}$. Let $i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ be such
>   that $i\geq2^{k}-n$.
>
> **(a)** Then, both numbers $i$ and $2^{k}-i-1$ are elements of $\left[
> n\right]  ^{\prime}$, and at least one of them is $\geq2^{k-1}$.
>
> **(b)** Let $\sigma$ be a nimble permutation of $\left[  n\right]
> ^{\prime}$. Then, $\sigma\left(  i\right)  =2^{k}-i-1$.

*Proof of Lemma 2.* **(a)** From $i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$, we obtain
$i\leq n-1<n\leq2^{k}$, so that $2^{k}-i>0$ and thus $2^{k}-i-1\geq0$. But
$i\geq2^{k}-n$, so that $i+n\geq2^{k}$ and thus $2^{k}-i\leq n$. Thus,
$\underbrace{2^{k}-i}_{\leq n}-1\leq n-1$. Combining this with $2^{k}
-i-1\geq0$, we obtain $2^{k}-i-1\in\left[  0,n-1\right]  =\left[  n\right]
^{\prime}$. Thus, both numbers $i$ and $2^{k}-i-1$ are elements of $\left[
n\right]  ^{\prime}$ (since $i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ by assumption).
It remains to prove that at least one of them is $\geq2^{k-1}$.

Assume the contrary. Thus, none of these two numbers is $\geq2^{k-1}$. Hence,
they are both $<2^{k-1}$. In other words, $i<2^{k-1}$ and $2^{k}-i-1<2^{k-1}$.
From $i<2^{k-1}$, we obtain $i\leq2^{k-1}-1$ (since $i$ and $2^{k-1}$ are
integers). Hence,
\begin{equation}
2^{k}-1=\underbrace{i}_{\leq2^{k-1}-1}+\underbrace{2^{k}-i-1}_{<2^{k-1}
}<2^{k-1}-1+2^{k-1}=\underbrace{2\cdot2^{k-1}}_{=2^{k}}-1=2^{k}-1.
\end{equation}
This is absurd. This contradiction shows that our assumption was wrong. Hence,
the proof of Lemma 2 **(a)** is complete.

**(b)** Lemma 2 **(a)** shows that both numbers $i$ and $2^{k}-i-1$ are
elements of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$, and at least one of them is
$\geq2^{k-1}$. We are thus in one of the following two cases:

*Case 1:* We have $i\geq2^{k-1}$.

*Case 2:* We have $2^{k}-i-1\geq2^{k-1}$.

Let us first consider Case 1. In this case, we have $i\geq2^{k-1}$. But the
permutation $\sigma$ is nimble. Hence, the number $i+\sigma\left(  i\right)
+1$ is a power of $2$ (by the definition of "nimble"). In other words,
$i+\sigma\left(  i\right)  +1=2^{m}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider this
$m$.

From $2^{m}=\underbrace{i}_{\geq2^{k-1}}+\underbrace{\sigma\left(  i\right)
}_{\geq0}+\underbrace{1}_{>0}>2^{k-1}$, we obtain $m>k-1$. Thus, $m\geq k$
(since $m$ and $k$ are integers).

On the other hand, $i\leq n-1$ (since $i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$) and
$\sigma\left(  i\right)  \leq n-1$ (since $i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$).
Hence,
\begin{align*}
2^{m}  &  =\underbrace{i}_{\leq n-1}+\underbrace{\sigma\left(  i\right)
}_{\leq n-1}+1\leq\left(  n-1\right)  +\left(  n-1\right)  +1=2\underbrace{n}
_{\leq2^{k}}-1\\
&  \leq2\cdot2^{k}-1<2\cdot2^{k}=2^{k+1}.
\end{align*}
Hence, $m<k+1$, so that $m\leq k$ (since $m$ and $k$ are integers). Combining
this with $m\geq k$, we obtain $m=k$. Hence, $2^{m}=2^{k}$, so that
$i+\sigma\left(  i\right)  +1=2^{m}=2^{k}$ and thus $\sigma\left(  i\right)
=2^{k}-i-1$. This proves Lemma 2 **(b)** in Case 1.

Now, let us consider case 2. In this case, we have $2^{k}-i-1\geq2^{k-1}$. But
we know that $2^{k}-i-1$ is an element of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$.
Hence, there exists some $j\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ such that
$\sigma\left(  j\right)  =2^{k}-i-1$ (since $\sigma$ is a permutation of
$\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$). Consider this $j$. We have $\sigma\left(
j\right)  =2^{k}-i-1\geq2^{k-1}$. But the permutation $\sigma$ is nimble.
Hence, the number $j+\sigma\left(  j\right)  +1$ is a power of $2$ (by the
definition of "nimble"). In other words, $j+\sigma\left(  j\right)  +1=2^{m}$
for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider this $m$.

From $2^{m}=\underbrace{j}_{\geq2^{k-1}}+\underbrace{\sigma\left(  j\right)
}_{\geq0}+\underbrace{1}_{>0}>2^{k-1}$, we obtain $m>k-1$. Thus, $m\geq k$
(since $m$ and $k$ are integers).

On the other hand, $j\leq n-1$ (since $j\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$) and
$\sigma\left(  j\right)  \leq n-1$ (since $j\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$).
Hence,
\begin{align*}
2^{m}  &  =\underbrace{j}_{\leq n-1}+\underbrace{\sigma\left(  j\right)
}_{\leq n-1}+1\leq\left(  n-1\right)  +\left(  n-1\right)  +1=2\underbrace{n}
_{\leq2^{k}}-1\\
&  \leq2\cdot2^{k}-1<2\cdot2^{k}=2^{k+1}.
\end{align*}
Hence, $m<k+1$, so that $m\leq k$ (since $m$ and $k$ are integers). Combining
this with $m\geq k$, we obtain $m=k$. Hence, $2^{m}=2^{k}$, so that
$j+\sigma\left(  j\right)  +1=2^{m}=2^{k}$ and thus $\sigma\left(  j\right)
=2^{k}-j-1$. Comparing this with $\sigma\left(  j\right)  =2^{k}-i-1$, we find
$2^{k}-i-1=2^{k}-j-1$. Hence, $i=j$. Thus, $\sigma\left(  i\right)
=\sigma\left(  j\right)  =2^{k}-i-1$. This proves Lemma 2 **(b)** in Case 2.

We have now proven Lemma 2 **(b)** in both Cases 1 and 2. Thus, Lemma 2
**(b)** always holds.

> **Lemma 3.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $k$ be a positive integer
>   such that $2^{k-1}<n\leq2^{k}$. Let $\sigma$ be a nimble permutation of
>   $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$.
>
> **(a)** We have $2^{k}-n<n$.
>
> **(b)** The map $\sigma$ preserves the two subsets $\left[  2^{k}
> -n\right]  ^{\prime}$ and $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ of $\left[  n\right]
> ^{\prime}$ (in other words, it maps each of these two subsets into itself).
>
> **(c)** Let $\alpha$ be the restriction of $\sigma$ to the subset $\left[
> 2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$, regarded as a map $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]
> ^{\prime}\rightarrow\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Then, $\alpha$ is a
>   nimble permutation of $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$.
>
> **(d)** Let $\beta$ be the restriction of $\sigma$ to the subset $\left[
> 2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $, regarded as a map $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]
> \rightarrow\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $. Then, $\beta$ is the unique
>   order-reversing permutation of this subset (i.e., it is strictly decreasing as
>   a map).

*Proof of Lemma 3.* **(a)** We have $2^{k}=2\cdot\underbrace{2^{k-1}}
_{<n}<2n=n+n$, so that $2^{k}-n<n$. This proves Lemma 3 **(a)**.

**(b)** Let $i\in\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $. Hence, $2^{k}-n\leq i\leq
n-1$. Thus, $i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ and $i\geq2^{k}-n$. Thus, Lemma
2 **(b)** shows that
\begin{equation}
\sigma\left(  i\right)  =2^{k}-\underbrace{i}_{\leq n-1}-1\geq2^{k}-\left(
n-1\right)  -1=2^{k}-n.
\end{equation}
Combining this with $\sigma\left(  i\right)  =2^{k}-\underbrace{i}_{\geq
2^{k}-n}-1\leq2^{k}-\left(  2^{k}-n\right)  -1=n-1$, we obtain $\sigma\left(
i\right)  \in\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $.

Now, forget that we fixed $i$. We thus have shown that $\sigma\left(
i\right)  \in\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ for each $i\in\left[
2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $. In other words, the map $\sigma$ preserves the subset
$\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Since
$\sigma$ is a permutation of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$, we thus conclude
that $\sigma$ also preserves the complementary subset $\left[  n\right]
^{\prime}\setminus\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  =\left[  2^{k}-n\right]
^{\prime}$ of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Thus, Lemma 3 **(b)** is proven.

**(c)** Lemma 3 **(b)** shows that the permutation $\sigma$ of $\left[
n\right]  ^{\prime}$ preserves the subset $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$
of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Hence, it restricts to a permutation of this
subset $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Thus, $\alpha$ is a well-defined
permutation of $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$. It remains to show that
$\alpha$ is nimble. But this is clear, because $\alpha$ is a restriction of
the nimble permutation $\sigma$. Thus, Lemma 3 **(c)** is proven.

**(d)** Lemma 3 **(b)** shows that the permutation $\sigma$ of $\left[
n\right]  ^{\prime}$ preserves the subset $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ of
$\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Hence, it restricts to a permutation of this
subset $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $. Thus, $\beta$ is a well-defined
permutation of $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $. Each $i\in\left[
2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ satisfies
\begin{align*}
\beta\left(  i\right)   &  =\sigma\left(  i\right)  \qquad\left(  \text{since
}\beta\text{ is a restriction of }\sigma\right) \\
&  =2^{k}-i-1
\end{align*}
(by Lemma 2 **(b)**, since $i\geq2^{k}-n$); therefore, $\beta$ is the
permutation of $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ sending each $i$ to $2^{k}-i-1$.
In other words, $\beta$ is the unique order-reversing permutation of this
subset (i.e., it is strictly decreasing as a map). Thus, Lemma 3 **(d)** is proven.

> **Definition.** Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint sets. Let $\alpha$ be a
>   permutation of $A$. Let $\beta$ be a permutation of $B$. Then, the map
>   \begin{equation}
> A\cup B\rightarrow A\cup B,\qquad x\mapsto
> \begin{cases}
> \alpha\left(  x\right)  , & \text{if }x\in A;\\
> \beta\left(  x\right)  , & \text{if }x\in B
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   is a permutation of the set $A\cup B$. This permutation is called the *union*
>   of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and is denoted by $\alpha\cup\beta$.

We are now ready to prove Theorem 1:

*Proof of Theorem 1.* **(a)** We shall prove Theorem 1 **(a)** by strong
induction on $n$:

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume (as the induction hypothesis) that for each
$g\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $g<n$, there is a unique nimble permutation
$\sigma_{g}$ of $\left[  g\right]  ^{\prime}$. We want to prove that there is
a unique nimble permutation $\sigma_{n}$ of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$.

If $n\leq1$, then this is obvious (because there is a unique permutation of
$\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ in this case, and its nimbleness is trivially
verified). Thus, WLOG assume that $n>1$. Thus, there exists a unique positive
integer $k$ satisfying $2^{k-1}<n\leq2^{k}$ (namely, this $k$ is the smallest
positive integer $\ell$ satisfying $2^{\ell}\geq n$). Consider this $k$. We
have $2^{k}-n<n$ (this is proven as in Lemma 3 **(a)**). Hence, the induction
hypothesis (applied to $g=2^{k}-n$) shows that there is a unique nimble
permutation $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ of $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$.
Consider this $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$.

Let $\gamma$ be the unique order-reversing permutation of the interval
$\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ (that is, the unique strictly decreasing map
$\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  \rightarrow\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $).
Explicitly, $\gamma$ is given by $\gamma\left(  i\right)  =2^{k}-i-1$ for each
$i\in\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $.

The permutations $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ and $\gamma$ are permutations of two
complementary subsets of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ (namely, of the subsets
$\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$ and $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $,
respectively). Hence, their union $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma$ is a
well-defined permutation of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Furthermore, this
permutation $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma$ is nimble.

[*Proof.* Let $i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. We must prove that the number
$i+\left(  \sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma\right)  \left(  i\right)  +1$ is a power
of $2$.

If $i\in\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$, then $\left(  \sigma_{2^{k}-n}
\cup\gamma\right)  \left(  i\right)  =\sigma\left(  i\right)  $ and thus
$i+\underbrace{\sigma\left(  i\right)  }_{=\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\left(  i\right)
}+1=i+\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\left(  i\right)  +1$ is a power of $2$ (since
$\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ is nimble). Thus, if $i\in\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime
}$, then we are done. Hence, we WLOG assume that $i\notin\left[
2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Hence, $i\in\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}
\setminus\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}=\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $.
Therefore, $\left(  \sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma\right)  \left(  i\right)
=\gamma\left(  i\right)  =2^{k}-i-1$ (by the definition of $\gamma$), so that
$i+\left(  \sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma\right)  \left(  i\right)  +1=2^{k}$ is a
power of $2$. This completes this proof.]

Thus, there exists **at least one** nimble permutation of $\left[  n\right]
^{\prime}$ (namely, $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma$).

Now, let $\sigma$ be a nimble permutation of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$.

Lemma 3 **(b)** shows that the map $\sigma$ preserves the two subsets $\left[
2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$ and $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ of $\left[
n\right]  ^{\prime}$.

Let $\alpha$ be the restriction of $\sigma$ to the subset $\left[
2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$, regarded as a map $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]
^{\prime}\rightarrow\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Lemma 3 **(c)** shows
that $\alpha$ is a nimble permutation of $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$.
Thus, $\alpha=\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ (since $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ is the unique nimble
permutation $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ of $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$).

Let $\beta$ be the restriction of $\sigma$ to the subset $\left[
2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $, regarded as a map $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]
\rightarrow\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $. Lemma 3 **(d)** shows that $\beta$
is the unique order-reversing permutation of this subset. Thus, $\beta=\gamma$
(since the unique order-reversing permutation of this subset is $\gamma$).

The permutation $\sigma$ is the union of the permutations $\alpha$ and $\beta$
(since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the restrictions of $\sigma$ to two
complementary subsets). In other words, $\sigma=\alpha\cup\beta$. In view of
$\alpha=\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ and $\beta=\gamma$, this rewrites as $\sigma
=\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma$.

Now, forget that we fixed $\sigma$. We thus have shown that each nimble
permutation $\sigma$ of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ satisfies $\sigma
=\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma$. Hence, there exists **at most one** nimble
permutation of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. Since we already know that there
exists **at least one** such permutation, we thus conclude that there exists
**exactly one** such permutation. In other words, there is a unique nimble
permutation $\sigma_{n}$ of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$. This completes the
induction step. Hence, Theorem 1 **(a)** is proven.

**(b)** We shall prove Theorem 1 **(b)** by strong induction on $n$:

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume (as the induction hypothesis) that for each
$g\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $g<n$, the unique nimble permutation $\sigma_{g}$
of $\left[  g\right]  ^{\prime}$ has sign $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma_{g}
}=\left(  -1\right)  ^{g\left(  g-1\right)  /2}$. We want to prove that the
unique nimble permutation $\sigma_{n}$ of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ has
sign $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma_{n}}=\left(  -1\right)  ^{n\left(
n-1\right)  /2}$.

If $n\leq1$, then this is obvious. Hence, WLOG assume that $n>1$. Thus, there
exists a unique positive integer $k$ satisfying $2^{k-1}<n\leq2^{k}$ (namely,
this $k$ is the smallest positive integer $\ell$ satisfying $2^{\ell}\geq n$).
Consider this $k$. Notice that $k$ is positive; thus, $2^{k}$ is even.

We have $2^{k}-n<n$ (this is proven as in Lemma 3 **(a)**). Hence, the
induction hypothesis (applied to $g=2^{k}-n$) shows that the unique nimble
permutation $\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ of $\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$ has sign
\begin{equation}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma_{2^{k}-n}}=\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(
2^{k}-n\right)  \left(  2^{k}-n-1\right)  /2}.
\end{equation}

Let $\gamma$ be the unique order-reversing permutation of the interval
$\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $ (that is, the unique strictly decreasing map
$\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  \rightarrow\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $).
Explicitly, $\gamma$ is given by $\gamma\left(  i\right)  =2^{k}-i-1$ for each
$i\in\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $.

A well-known fact says the following: If $m\in\mathbb{N}$, and if $M$ is an
$m$-element set of integers, then the unique order-reversing permutation of
the set $M$ has sign $\left(  -1\right)  ^{m\left(  m-1\right)  /2}$. Applying
this to $m=2n-2^{k}$ and $M=\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]  $, we conclude that
the unique order-reversing permutation of the set $\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]
$ has $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  2n-2^{k}\right)  \left(  2n-2^{k}
-1\right)  /2}$. Since this permutation is $\gamma$, we thus have proven that
\begin{equation}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\gamma}=\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  2n-2^{k}\right)
\left(  2n-2^{k}-1\right)  /2}.
\end{equation}

In the proof of Theorem 1 **(a)**, we have shown that each nimble permutation
$\sigma$ of $\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ satisfies $\sigma=\sigma_{2^{k}
-n}\cup\gamma$. Applying this to $\sigma=\sigma_{n}$, we conclude that
$\sigma_{n}$ satisfies $\sigma_{n}=\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma$.

But if $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint finite sets, and if $\alpha$ and $\beta$
are permutations of $A$ and $B$ (respectively), then the union $\alpha
\cup\beta$ of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ has sign $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\alpha
\cup\beta}=\left(  -1\right)  ^{\alpha}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\beta}$. Applying
this to $A=\left[  2^{k}-n\right]  ^{\prime}$, $B=\left[  2^{k}-n,n-1\right]
$, $\alpha=\sigma_{2^{k}-n}$ and $\beta=\gamma$, we conclude that the union
$\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma$ has sign
\begin{align*}
\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma} &  =\underbrace{\left(
-1\right)  ^{\sigma_{2^{k}-n}}}_{=\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  2^{k}-n\right)
\left(  2^{k}-n-1\right)  /2}}\underbrace{\left(  -1\right)  ^{\gamma}
}_{=\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  2n-2^{k}\right)  \left(  2n-2^{k}-1\right)
/2}}\\
&  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  2^{k}-n\right)  \left(  2^{k}-n-1\right)
/2}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  2n-2^{k}\right)  \left(  2n-2^{k}-1\right)
/2}\\
&  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{\left(  2^{k}-n\right)  \left(  2^{k}-n-1\right)
/2+\left(  2n-2^{k}\right)  \left(  2n-2^{k}-1\right)  /2}\\
&  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{n\left(  n-1\right)  /2}
\end{align*}
(since
\begin{equation}
\left(  2^{k}-n\right)  \left(  2^{k}-n-1\right)  /2+\left(  2n-2^{k}\right)
\left(  2n-2^{k}-1\right)  /2\equiv n\left(  n-1\right)  /2\operatorname{mod}2
\end{equation}
(because
\begin{align*}
&  \left(  2^{k}-n\right)  \left(  2^{k}-n-1\right)  /2+\left(  2n-2^{k}
\right)  \left(  2n-2^{k}-1\right)  /2-n\left(  n-1\right)  /2\\
&  =\left(  n-2^{k}\right)  \underbrace{\left(  2n-2^{k}\right)
}_{\substack{\equiv0\operatorname{mod}2\\\text{(since }2^{k}\text{ is even)}
}}\equiv0\operatorname{mod}2
\end{align*}
)). In view of $\sigma_{n}=\sigma_{2^{k}-n}\cup\gamma$, this rewrites as
$\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma_{n}}=\left(  -1\right)  ^{n\left(  n-1\right)
/2}$. So we have proven that the unique nimble permutation $\sigma_{n}$ of
$\left[  n\right]  ^{\prime}$ has sign $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\sigma_{n}
}=\left(  -1\right)  ^{n\left(  n-1\right)  /2}$. This completes the induction
step. Hence, Theorem 1 **(b)** is proven.

**Remark.** Our recursive proof of Theorem 1 **(a)** can be used to show that
the permutation $\sigma_{n}$ is an involution (i.e., it equals its own
inverse) and has no fixed points except possibly $1$ (because the permutation
$\gamma$ is an order-reversing permutation of a set of even size, and such
permutations never have fixed points). Thus, the cycle type of $\sigma_{n}$ is
$\left(  \underbrace{2,2,\ldots,2}_{n/2\text{ times}}\right)  $ when $n$ is
even, and $\left(  \underbrace{2,2,\ldots,2}_{\left(n-1\right)/2\text{ times}},1\right)  $
otherwise. This gives another way of computing the sign of $\sigma_{n}$, and
thus of proving Theorem 1 **(b)**.

Comment: @ darij: thank you for this very clear and instructive proof!

Comment: Very impressive !

Answer (score 2):

Edit: following our exchange, I modify the presentation of what is now a partial result.

I will stick to your notations. For example $H_8$ is the $2^3 \times 2^3 $ Hankel matrix:

$$H_{8}:=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
      \end{pmatrix}$$

We are going to prove a restricted version of your result, i.e., we will prove that, for $k\geq 2$:

$$\det(H_{2^k})=1$$

complying with formula $(-1)^{\binom{2^k}{2}}=(-1)^{\tfrac{2^k(2^k-1)}{2}}=1.$

Let us set, for notational convenience, $K_n=H_{2^n}$.

$K_n$ possesses a recursive structure with the form :

$$\tag{1}K_{n+1}= \begin{pmatrix}K_{n} & J_{n}\\J_{n} & 0_{n}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $J_n$ is the anti-diagonal matrix (with ones on the secondary diagonal) and  $0_{n}$ is the all-zero matrix, both of size $2^n \times 2^n$.

Now (1) allows to work by recursion for obtaining $\det(K_n)$ by using the Schur formula for $2 \times 2$ block-defined matrices :

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\C & D\end{pmatrix} \ \ \implies \ \ \det(M)=\det(A)det(D-CA^{-1}B)$$

giving here:

$$det(K_{n+1})=\det(K_n)\det(-JK_{n}^{-1}J)=\det(K_n)\det(-I)\det(J)\det(K_{n}^{-1})\det(J)=$$

$$det(-I)det(J_n^2)\det(K_nK_{n}^{-1})=(-1)^{2^n}=\begin{cases}-1 & (n=0)\\+1& (n>0) \end{cases}$$

(where $I$ denotes the identity matrix with $2^n \times 2^n$ elements).

Explanations: $\det(J_n^2)=\det(I)=1$ and $\det(-I_k)=(-1)^k$.

---

A Matlab program for the recursive generation of matrix $K_{2^p}$ (here with $p=2$):

> ```
> p=2;
> K=[1];J=[1];Z=[0];
> for k=1:p
>    K=[K,J;J,Z]
>    J=[Z,J;J,Z];
>    Z=[Z,Z;Z,Z];
> end;
> K
> ```
>
> Edit : I wonder if a simple solution couldn't be achieved by using [Lucas Theorem] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake which is now corrected. But what you denote by $H_{3}$ is in my notation $H_{8}$.

Comment: For example $\det{H_{2}}= \det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 
      \end{pmatrix}= -1$ and $\det{H_{3}}= \det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1&0 \\1 & 0 &1\\0 &1&0
      \end{pmatrix}= -1$.

Comment: I see. I thought the matrices were $2^n \times 2^n$. My method should still be applicable (the $2 \times 2$ block formulation I give with the Schur determinant formula does not necessitate to have $B$ and $C$ square. Only $A$ and $D$ *must* be square).

Comment: I have modified my text in order to comply with your objectives. I confirm also  the signs checked on a large number of simulations. I haven't found till now how to tackle the general case.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting computation of $H_{2^n}$. 

This special case is also almost obvious from the usual definition of a determinant $detA=\sum{a_{1,p(1)}a_{2,p(2)}\dots a_{n,p(n)}}$ over all permutations $p$, because in this case we have ones in the secondary diagonal. The sign of the corresponding permutation is $\binom{n}{2}.$

It seems that also in the general case only one permutation is possible, but I cannot give a precise proof of this fact.

Comment: You are right !

Comment: I have had a look at your rich exchanges with @darij greenberg. On my side, I have discovered a one-line proof of the particular case $2^n \times 2^n$ ;) it suffices to left-multiply $H_n$ by $J_n$ (notation as in my answer) to get a "+90° rotated" version of $H_n$, i.e. a  lower diagonal matrix with its diagonal filled with ones ; thus $\det(H_n)=1$...

Comment: I will do an edit to my answer.